# Grub does not boot into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Currently I have GNU GRUB version 2.02beta2-36ubuntu3.18 installed and Ubuntu and windows installed.

When I turn on my computer and I choose Windows Boot Manager on grub, it boots back into grub again and I am not able to boot back to windows. It boots the Ubuntu normally when I choose Ubuntu.

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: You haven't provided any Ubuntu release details, but the `grub` you mention is an old one and very out-dated & not a currently supported/patched by Ubuntu, so are you using Ubuntu at all? or a system that was based on Ubuntu but is off-topic here?

Comment: For GRUB to be able to boot both Windows and Ubuntu, both OS need to be installed in the same BIOS or UEFI mode. GRUB from Ubuntu installed in Legacy mode will not boot Windows installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: My Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS but I dont want to use that anymore. How am I able to boot to windows again? I would like to re-do the ubuntu installation.

Comment: FYI: A *xenial* (16.04) system should have grub `2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.29` so your system is well behind on upgrades (if it's 16.04; you've got a 19-Mar-2018 deprecated package) so I'd start by fixing that (ie. `sudo apt update` looking for any issues/errors, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and reboot if necessary, then try and `update-grub` again)

Comment: I have tried the updates but the grub version remains the same.

Comment: Which maybe a clue as to your issue..  Did you get a clean `sudo apt update` with all lines present (esp. `xenial-updates` or `xenial-security` , no warnings or errors... followed by the `sudo apt full-upgrade` as the version you state has not been used by Ubuntu since 2018 so you're likely using something else (& not Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or you missed details in the `apt update` messages)

Comment: I have tried sudo apt update and it does not have any error. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QVwgJ5l7maLoHJDjjcxQBhtYDIxM69wh/view?usp=sharing
I have not used the computer since a long time ago as it was just passed to me to resolve, maybe thats why the versions are outdated. I intend to just restore back to windows but i cant seem to boot windows at all.

Comment: If you `sudo update-grub` (update the grub menu of what OSes are available for boot), does it see your windows system? (ie. if seen it'll be listed in the output).  If it's seen there but not when you boot grub; then the MBR isn't owned by that 16.04 system (maybe you had an older dual boot system...) which can be fixed via `grub-install`.. otherwise what C.S.Cameron suggested comes to mind..

Comment: I can see windows bootloader appearing in grub, but every time I click it it will reload grub again. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RGY9mdZ7TtlnwBuvvDrh-Oe4QFestk4N/view?usp=sharing

Ubuntu seems to be in EFI mode, but I am not sure how to check for windows https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p8tt8gN0XXXtuZZ1K_r6hKl52VDpGpGx/view?usp=sharing